# Compare and exclude string keywords from an array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, arraylist, match

I have a set of string keywords and a set of array list to compare and exclude items from the final string display. I inserted a split to isolate each string.

Here's the code:

```
var keywords = "Did the cow jump over the moon?";
var keywords_parsed = keywords.split(" ");
var exclusionlist = ["a","is","of","in","on","it","to","if","so","the","i","we","did"];
```

Final string display should be

```
cow, jump, over, moon
```

The code should exclude "Did", "the", and the other "the".

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What's your question? In other words, what have you tried that's not working?

Comment: I need to use the exclusionlist (array) to be the master list for all strings to be excluded from the keywords variable. So, if the keywords vary, then the exclusionlist will work as a filter of unnecessary items to be displayed i.e. cow, jump, over, moon

Comment: Yes, but that's a code request, not a programming question. You should try to Google some things first and then give us what you've tried so that we can see what the issue is and improve your existing code instead of writing it for you: it'll help you remember it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [javascript array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is what you are looking for. You could do something like this to achieve what you want.

```
var keywords = "Did the cow jump over the moon?";

// change lowercase then split the words into array
var keywords_parsed = keywords.toLowerCase().split(" ");

var exclusionlist = ["a","is","of","in","on","it","to","if","so","the","i","we","did"];

// now filter out the exclusionlist
keywords_parsed.filter(function(x) { return exclusionlist.indexOf(x) < 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneliner, just for fun:

```
keywords.match(/\w+/g)
        .map(function(i) {return i.toLowerCase();})
        .filter(function(i) { return exclusionlist.indexOf(i) == -1; })
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4KSKQ/

Comment: This worked too on a different approach, thanks @zerkms.